# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

I am beginner to Fluent Nhibernate.  i have created one sample application in asp.net mvc 3 with Fluent Nhibernate. here is the code that i am using for initialisation.

> private static void initialisationFactory()
>           {
>               try
>               {
>                   _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()                                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(@"Server=10.10.10.10;Database=Product_Demo;uid=sa;pwd=12345;Trusted_Connection=false;"))
>     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf< CompanyEntity >().ExportTo("d:\"))
>     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf< ModuleEntity>().ExportTo("d:\"))
>     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf< RoleEntity>().ExportTo("d:\"))
>     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf< UserEntity>().ExportTo("d:\"))
>                                   .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg))
>                                   .BuildSessionFactory();
>               }
>               catch (Exception e)
>               {
>                   throw;
>               }
>           }

Now is it necessory to add .Mapping.....  lines for all tables? like below..

> .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf().ExportTo("d:\"))

And will it be increase memory of the project while running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to do it once. Point it to where your entities are:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>.ExportTo("d:\"))
```

where `Product` is a class in your project where all the rest of your classes are declared/included.

Comment: If i have more than one tables entity

Comment: Like I said, that will do it ;)  If you are thinking of overriding some configurations then that's another thing. You can do something like: `public class ProductOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Product>`.